# QT Why dont see a customwidget painted by a delegates?

Tags: c++, qt

I have a model / view schema.
I’m developing a general multipurpose delegates, and I’d want to use some custom widgets I have.
The first I have tested does not work:

```
void A_delegates::paint(QPainter* painter, const QStyleOptionViewItem & option,
 const QModelIndex& index) const
QRect the_rect(option.rect);    
A_file_chooser file_chooser;
file_chooser.setGeometry(QRect(QPoint(0,0), the_rect.size()));
file_chooser.render(painter,the_rect.topLeft());
```

I see an empty cell ?
I have read the doc searching something usefull about this but without success.
Can anybody help me ? Thanks.

( the file chooser is as simple as a label plus a button. I can see it in other scenarios)

Answer (score 0):

You're trying fit file chooser to the cell and force it to render into your widget. But file chooser isn't child of anything, is isn't initialized yet, so it will just skip the render. In `paint` function of the delegate you must use given painter to draw something. Do you want *static* button image in the cell? It can't be clicked! You need real file chooser in the cell, added as a child to get it working.

Comment: I'm going to do this at the createeditor.... Or can't I? (I'm going to appliya eddittrigerr - onclick , so I suposse that I'm going to have a createeditor and the possibility of having the button ready to be clicked). In case of I'd want a full widget I'd have to create it and place it over the table ? Thanks for your help !

Comment: See http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qtablewidget.html#setCellWidget - you can add real widget to the table cell.